# как получить ssl сертификат (не приватный ключ) чужого сайта (как браузер это делает)

Tags: node.js, ssl, https

Получить header'ы, содержимое сайта и т.д. известно и понятно как, но информации как получить ssl сертификат я не нашёл, именно сам сертификат, ведь первым делом это делает браузер при https соединение, получает и проверяет на подлинность его... пишу на node, не откажусь от примера но хотя бы в теории узнать, хотя бы узнать куда копать

(Чуть дополнения)

Может ли кто вообще рассказать весь путь, мол..

браузер видя домен, идёт в dns, берёт ip и идёт туда, допустим видит переход на https и тут... что дальше? как и в каком порядке действует браузер, как он договаривается с сайтом о приватном ключе, как он и где проверяет подлинность сертификата и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В прицнипе из теории можете прочитать про tls, в частности [спецификации](https://tls.dxdt.ru/tls.html#certs), там расписана идея протокола, а именно в какой момент сервер отправляет свой сертификат.

Кстати вот очень подробный и детализированный ответ на полную последовательность действий браузера. [клац](https://habr.com/ru/company/htmlacademy/blog/254825/)

Так же на соседней стороне, похожий вопрос был. [клац](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596315/how-to-get-ssl-certificate-information-using-node-js)